# Ajax call not functioning properly in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to create a comments section for a blog. I'm having trouble identifying the opened blog posts id in my jquery.

I'm getting these errors from the chrome console

```
GET http://localhost:46223/api/posts//comments
```

the postid should be inbetween the double slash but its not. When I manually enter the postID inside the ajax call it works perfectly.

An Api Controller is exposing the comments from the database, relevant code below.

```
[Route("api/posts/{postId:long}/comments")]
    public class CommentsController : Controller
    {
        readonly BlogDataContext _dbContext;
        public CommentsController(BlogDataContext db)
        {
            _dbContext = db;

        }
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Comment> Get(long postId)
        {
            return _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.PostId == postId);
        }
```

When I press the "Show Comments" link it chrome console gives me the error I was talking about earlier. Relevant code from my partial view below. The most important line from below is only the first one.

```
<a href="#" class="show-comments">Show Comments</a>
                        <div class="comments-container hide">
                            <h3>Comments</h3>
                            <div class="comments">
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="add-comment">Add a comment</a>
                                <div class="new-comment hide">
                                    <form role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea name="Body" class="new-comment form-control" placeholder="Enter comment here..."></textarea>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create Comment</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Relevant code snippets from my .js

```
 $(document).on('click', '.show-comments', function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        new Post(this).showComments();
        return false;
    });

function Post(el) {

    var $el = $(el),
        postEl = $el.hasClass('blog-post') ? $el : $el.parents('.blog-post'),
        postId = postEl.data('post-id'),
        addCommentEl = postEl.find('.add-comment'),
        newCommentEl = postEl.find('.new-comment'),
        commentEl = newCommentEl.find('[name=Body]'),
        commentsContainer = postEl.find('.comments-container'),
        commentsEl = postEl.find('.comments'),
        showCommentsButton = postEl.find('.show-comments'),
        noCommentsEl = postEl.find('.no-comments');



    return {
        addComment: addComment,
        renderComment: renderComments,
        showAddComment: showAddComment,
        showComments: showComments,
    };

function showComments() {
        PostCommentService.getComments(postId).then(renderComments);
    }


var PostCommentService = (
    function PostCommentService() {

        function call(postId, method, data) {
            return $.ajax({
                // RESTful Web API URL:  /api/posts/{postId}/comments
                url: ['/api/posts', postId, 'comments'].join('/'), // If I Change the 'postId' here to an integer of an existing postId, it works perfectly.
                type: method,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
        }

        return {

            // Add comment by calling URL with POST method and passing data
            addComment: function (comment) {
                return call(comment.PostId, 'POST', comment);
            },

            // Get comments by calling URL with GET method
            getComments: function (postId) {
                return call(postId, 'GET');
            }
        };
    })();
```

[Full .js file](http://pastebin.com/Xt75g31t)

I'm sorry if I missed to include something, but I have a lot of code. If you need to know anything else let me know.

I'd also be grateful just for some suggestions where my error might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting the post id from the data attribute `post-id` of the postEl. postEl could be the same anchor tag which was clicked or it's parent with `blog-post` css class.

```
var $el = $(el),
postEl = $el.hasClass('blog-post') ? $el : $el.parents('.blog-post'),
postId = postEl.data('post-id'),
```

But in your HTML markup, there is no such data attribute for the anchor tag. So if you add that, your code will be able to get the post id and use that to build the url

```
<a href="#" class="show-comments blog-post" data-post-id="250">Show Comments</a>
```

I hard coded 250 as the value for the `data-post-id` attribute. You may replace it with a value coming from your model.

```
<a href="#" class="show-comments blog-post" data-post-id="@Model.PostId">Show Comments</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! My comments section was inside a div blog-post class so I just added the data-post-id attribute there and it worked! Thanks alot